# Retrieving data using a pointer in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform, fetch, parse-cloud-code

I am having a hard time doing something that should be simple. I must be missing something obvious.
In Parse.com cloud code, I have a pointer (p) to an object in a Class (myClass).
How can I get hold of the object in myClass, using the pointer (p)?

Searching the net makes me think I should be using fetch().

But however I tried failed. It seems like my fetch is just ignored.

I have used variations of this code pattern, all with the same failing result:

```
anObject.get("pointer").fetch()
{
}
```

for example with:

```
console.log("SIGNAL--BEFORE");
anObject.get("pointer").fetch({
    success: function(myObject) {
        console.log("ALL--OOKK");
    }
});
console.log("SIGNAL--AFTER");
```

I never see the "ALL--OOKK" in the logs. Though I can see both "SIGNAL--BEFORE" and "SIGNAL--AFTER".

I have verified that anObject.get("pointer") is a valid objectId, so the problem has to be in the way I use fetch.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `find()` as well:

```
    var myClassQuery = new Parse.Query("myClass");
    myClassQuery.include("pointer"); //where "pointer" is a column name
    myClassQuery.find().then(function (results) {
        //success code
    }, function (err) {
        //error code
    });
```

Include multi-level pointers by just using dot(.)
For e.g. `myClassQuery.include("pointer1.pointer2")`. Where `pointer1` is column of myClass and `pointer2` is column of `pointer1`'s class.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You need to pass a success function to the function fetch().

```
anObject.get("pointer").fetch({
    success: function(result) {

        // result is an ParseObject of your "pointer" class

        // If there is a column called "title" in your "pointer" class
        // you can get the data by...

        var title = result.get('title');
        response.success(title);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error('Error: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Michel I've updated my answer. I added a error callback. Please let me know what the error message is. Thanks.

Comment: I had tried before, including the error function (as you do). And neither the success nor the error fired. Like the fetch was totally bypassed.
I am not using fetch as it ought to be used. I am working with promises, so may be a mistake somewhere. In the meantime I tried using : .include("pointer") that seems to work.

Comment: Oh, if you are using Promise, maybe you call `response.success();` somewhere else, so the function is end before `fetch()` gets its return value. A complete code may help a lot. And as you said, `include()` works too, so if you need to fetch lots of times, just use `include()`.

Comment: You are right :) I am definitely not a master yet with promises.
At the moment I am fighting, with this other issue (still on Parse):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929407/function-not-updating-on-parse-com