# Function not updating on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have this function, working normally, on Parse.com:

```
Parse.Cloud.job
 ("myBGFunction", function(request, status)
 {
 console.log("Entering myBGFunction.");
 });
```

But as strange as it may seem, if I update it (saving and using parse deploy) as usual with the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.job
 ("myBGFunction", function(request, status)
 {
 console.log("Entering myBGFunction (AAAA).");
 });
```

The next time I try to execute, the old function is executed (in the log), as if the update did go through, though I got no error message after running:

```
parse deploy
```

Has anyone seen this before?

One more tiny question: Is there a way to clear the old logs (on Parse)?
That would be a basic useful feature.

Looking a bit more into details at what happens to my classes, it seems like "all is fine" except that what I can see in the log is outdated. That is as I wrote earlier, logs from previous versions.
It makes it extremely difficult to debug a function, because all trace-log becomes impossible.

Comment: This happens to me all the time its driving me nuts. Did you figure out what the issue is?

Comment: No I think it just disappeared as it came.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the "CloudCode" section, and check if the code is the same as you expected.

[image]

Comment: Yes I just checked and it is what I expect, but wen executing, it is not the last version of the code.

Comment: It didn't happen to me. You should go to https://www.parse.com/help and click "Report a bug". Good luck.

Comment: Well, it never happened to me before.